# How can i use desgin pattern in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am flex developer,

I have created multiple application in flex. But i did not use any design pattern in my application.

How can i start using design pattern in my flex application.
I know there is MVC (Model View Control )pattern and many other patterns

Which pattern is more useful and how can i start using this pattern in my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most applications have a natural progressions due to size and complexity to start using frameworks which will either force or suggest the use of some of the most common design patterns.

You question suggests you want a better structure in your application maybe?

If this is the case I would look at how frameworks are implemented and used in Flex such as

Parsley
Robotlegs
Mate
etc...

If you are looking to improve your coding in general as design patterns are agnostic of language I would read "ActionScript 3.0 Design Patterns - O'Reilly".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you watch PatternCraft videos on youtube http://goo.gl/vmc0e

Also download, investigate code, and try to use:

- Robotlegs
- Parsley

Please read [Best-Practices](https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/Best-Practices)

All source codes available on github. I recommend you join to community and commit your code.